# Async.whilst with requests and unknown page limit - how to make requests asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, underscore.js

So I have written a scrip which works nicely, but I want to make the requests asynchronous. Currently, each one runs after the previous has finished, I had to do it this way because I have no way of knowing the total # of pages. I have to hit the requests until I get an error.

Is there a better way of writing this code?

var getResponse = 'true';
var newNum = 0;
var responses = [];

async.whilst(
    function () { 
      // starts the async while loop
      return getResponse == 'true';

```
},
function (callback) {
    // calls everytime
    newNum++;
    console.log('num',newNum);

    var options = {
        url: 'http://upload-api.kooaba.com/api/v4/buckets/sdfsfsfsfsdfsd/items?page='+newNum,
    }

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {

      var info = JSON.parse(body);

      if(info.offset) {
        getResponse = false;
        console.log('end of the records');
        console.log("All loaded.");
        var jsonSize = _.size(responses);
        console.log('size',jsonSize);
        res.json(responses);

      }
      else {
        _.each(info, function(obj) {
          var imageObj = {
            uuid : obj.uuid,
            enabled: obj.enabled,
            title: obj.title,
            itemCode: obj.reference_id,
            num_images: obj.num_images,
            bucket: 'uk'
          }
          responses.push(imageObj);
      });
        callback();
      }


      });

},
function (err) {
    // End loop
    console.log('end');
}
```

);

Answer (score 0):

Async.js tends to work on known sets of data, and will not accept changes to them once initiated.

Since no one else replied, I'm posing a general idea for loop based processing of the apps. This is a hacky way to do what you seek using a **synchronous** while loop, although this might need to be optimized as it may prove as CPU costly:

```
var flag = false; // Will be used to indicate loop break time.
var expectedResponses = 0; // Will count sent requests
var arrRequests = []; // Will be used as the queue, constantly getting requests pushed.
var arrResponses = []; // Will be used to keep the responses.

while (!flag || expectedResponses < arrResponses.length) {
    if (arrRequests.length) {
        var requestParams = arrRequests.pop();
        expectedResponses++;
        request(requestParams, function cb(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                // Handle error and:
                expectedResponses--;
                return;
            }
            arrResponses.push(res);
        });
    }
}

// Process responses here.
// This code will not be reached before flag is raised, AND queue is processed.
```

Explanation: This sync loop does not wait for a callback. It will iterate every time the internal code is processed, and the closing `}` is reached. The reason being it waiting for a return statement, which is received as a `return null;`

Note flag should be raised manually to allow breaking of the loop once all requests had received a response.
Also, you might want to consider re-writing this as event based, having new request event, and a second event which fires once flag is raised and last response is received..